# Configuration Glassfish 3.1.2 Connection Pool to PostgreSQL Using SSL

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, connection-pooling, glassfish-3, postgresql-9.1

I can easily set up a connection pool from glassfish to postgres in an unsecured manner. However I am trying to get a connection pool connection using SSL. I have SSL set up using a CA cert on the PostgreSQL server, and can (verified) connect to the server using PgAdmin using SSL. But I can't get Glassfish to do the same.

I know that there must be more to it than just configuring the ssl parameter in the connection pool advanced to 'true', but I can't find any information on the subject, and I have googled all over. There are some MySQL related articles, but nothing with postgres. I did add the ca crt to the keystore are restarted the server, but I get this unhelpful message in the log file:

> [#|2015-02-01T15:35:56.832-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service|_ThreadID=187;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR8054:
>   Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [
>   DevtestPool ], Connection could not be allocated because: The
>   connection attempt failed.|#]

The PostreSQL server is logging this error:

> LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown